# Make targets using % are not working as in "Nothing to be done"

Tags: go, makefile

I'm trying to compile all my apps from the cmd folder but somehow this makefile is not working.

```
GO_BUILD_FLAGS =
APPS           = my-app another-app stuff

define BUILD_BINARY =
    @echo go build $(GO_BUILD_FLAGS) -o $@ ./$<
    go build $(GO_BUILD_FLAGS) -o $@ ./$<
endef

FORCE: ;

bin/%: cmd/% FORCE
    $(BUILD_BINARY)

build: $(addprefix bin/,$(APPS))
```

I'm continously facing following output, no matter I try.

```sh
$ make build
make: Nothing to be done for `build'.
$ make bin/my-app
make: Nothing to be done for `bin/my-app'.
$ make bin/another-app
make: Nothing to be done for `bin/another-app'.
$ make bin/stuff
make: Nothing to be done for `bin/stuff'.
```

Despite `FORCE` the `bin/` targets are not executed. What am I missing?

Running this on `MacOS` using `GNU Make 3.81`.

This is how my folder looks like:

```
$ tree cmd
cmd
├── another-app
│   └── main.go
├── my-app
│   └── main.go
└── stuff
    └── main.go

3 directories, 3 files
```

when running `make` with `-d` I get following:

https://pastebin.com/wh6TWxj9 (didn't fit in body as it has a 30000 char limit)

Comment: I can't reproduce this, with a modern version of GNU make.  Does the file `cmd/my-app` (etc.) exist?  You will need to run `make -d bin/my-app` and look at the output to see why make decides there's nothing to be done.  To me it looks like (a) the file `bin/my-app` exists and (b) the file `cmd/my-app` doesn't exist, so make doesn't match the rule.  But, the GNU make version shipped with MacOS is known to be buggy so maybe it's a bug.

Comment: BTW, `PHONY: FORCE` is wrong.  I guess you meant `.PHONY: FORCE`.

Comment: Also the commas (`,`) do not belong in the value of `APPS`.  They are interpreted as ordinary characters, not item delimiters.

Comment: Not really a direct answer, but maybe you can use something simpler than make. I like https://taskfile.dev :-)

Comment: In addition to what others have said about the commas and the lines with FORCE and PHONY (just remove these, you don't need .PHONY if you use FORCE), please show the result of `ls -l cmd`

Comment: @badzen I have added the contents of cmd folder. @madscientist I have included the output of `make -d bin/my-app`

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the issue. However I do not understand yet why the `define` doesn't work.

In the end I just removed:

```
define BUILD_BINARY =
    @echo go build $(GO_BUILD_FLAGS) -o $@ ./$<
    go build $(GO_BUILD_FLAGS) -o $@ ./$<
endef
```

and replaced the original bin target

```
bin/%: cmd/% FORCE
    $(BUILD_BINARY)
```

with

```
bin/%: cmd/% FORCE
    go build $(GO_BUILD_FLAGS) -o $@ ./$<
```

Then it starts working.